# Extract Top 5 Values for Each Group in a List Based on Specific Criteria without VBA

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have developed a formula to extract the top value from a list. Now I would like to update the formula with the ability to filter the list to identify the top value if Column Q contains "Y".

```
=INDEX('Inventory Turnover'!$B:$B,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Inventory Turnover'!$K:$K=LARGE('Inventory Turnover'!$K:$K,ROWS('Inventory Turnover'!C$1:C1)))*(COUNTIF('Inventory Turnover'!C$1:C1,'Inventory Turnover'!$B:$B)=0),),0))
```

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration! Please let me know if my request is unclear and/or if you have any specific questions. Appreciate any support!

Comment: You realise that VBA would probably be a lot more readable than that mess you have at the moment :-)

Comment: Please don't use whole column references for something like this.  It can cause slow calculations rather easily.  You should limit your ranges to just your rows of data.  If you want the ranges to pick up new data as it is entered, please use a [dynamic named range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#Dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that can be done by a pivot table with a few clicks. Insert a pivot table that points to the data, drag a label to the rows panel, drag the value field to the values panel. Filter the pivot table to show the top ten or adjust to show top x numbers.

Now use a slicer or a page filter to filter the pivot table on any other field.